# Integrate Millennial ads over Admob crashes the apps after closing of interstitial ad

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, millennial-media

I'm facing a problem that I tried to google for a solution whole day but no related topic.

I implemented admob which running fine for all kinds of ads(banner, rectangle, interstitial etc.), then I follow the Admob Mediation instruction for integrating various of different network such as Inmobi and mMedia.

The integration for Inmobi is fine, I can get both banner and interstitial displayed on my apps. However, my app crashed whenever I either close or click on the mMedia ads. I got the following error in the console:

```
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.google.ads.mediation.millennial.MillennialAdapter$InterstitialListener.MMAdOverlayClosed(MillennialAdapter.java)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.millennialmedia.android.MMSDK$Event$5.run(MMSDK.java:527)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.millennialmedia.android.MMSDK.runOnUiThread(MMSDK.java:641)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.millennialmedia.android.MMSDK$Event.overlayClosed(MMSDK.java:517)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity.finishSuper(MMActivity.java:251)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.millennialmedia.android.MMBaseActivity.finish(MMBaseActivity.java:161)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.millennialmedia.android.AdViewOverlayActivity.finish(AdViewOverlayActivity.java:186)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity.finish(MMActivity.java:240)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.millennialmedia.android.AdViewOverlayView$AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd(AdViewOverlayView.java:411)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at android.view.animation.Animation$3.run(Animation.java:374)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-17 02:12:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 02:17:49.897: I/Process(1923): Sending signal. PID: 1923 SIG: 9
02-17 02:17:51.077: V/WebViewChromium(2011): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b2d66f10}
02-17 02:17:51.087: I/chromium(2011): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
02-17 02:17:51.107: I/BrowserProcessMain(2011): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
02-17 02:17:51.187: E/chromium(2011): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-17 02:17:51.187: E/chromium(2011): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-17 02:17:51.197: E/chromium(2011): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-17 02:17:51.197: E/chromium(2011): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-17 02:17:51.197: E/chromium(2011): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? please kindly help, thanks.

Comment: Solved the problem finally. It was due to incorrect adaptor version. The issue disappeared by updating the new version of adaptor.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer. And include details of what versions you were using and what versions you needed to use.